# Passing variables to a querystring within a vuejs component

Tags: vue.js

I have a script I've used from [codepen](https://codepen.io/Flamov/pen/NwpzZO) to create Tinder-like swipe cards. It all works fine except for one thing - I need to pass a querystring with variables so when the user swipes right they are taken to another page. In this section of code I can do this if the URL is plain like so:

```
if (!approved) {
                position.x = -x;
                position.rotation = -maxRotation;
                icon.type = 'pass';
            }else{                      
                window.location.href = "recipe.html"
            }

            icon.opacity = 1;
            setTimeout(() => this.showing = false, 200);
        }
    },
```

(full code is on the Codepen link above)

But if I try and pass vars to the querystring it doesn't work. I've tried:

```
window.location.href = "recipe.html?recipeid="+idMeal;
```

And

```
window.location.href = "recipe.html?recipeid="+{{ idMeal }};
```

And even

```
window.location.href = "recipe.html?recipeid="+`${idMeal}`;
```

But I can't get it to work. Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: *it doesn't work* **is not a helpful problem description**.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
router.push({ path: 'swipe', query: { plan: 'beauty lady' } })
```

documented here
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html